# store the date in the cache and when the user is logged in save it in the Realtime database in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating a Habit app on Android and I want to store the offline habit data in the cache so that the client can create, edit, search by date, score, strike the habits and if they like it they can log in with their Google account and save all the habits cache in the database

How to do this?

I know Firebase only store in cache when he retrive from realtime database like

```
habitsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users")
habitsRef.keepSynced(true)

habitsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        for(dataSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
            println("******************* Load **************")
            println(dataSnapshot)
        }
    }

    override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
      println("************Error*****************")
    }
})
```

If I create a Sqlite to store all the habits in cache it will be double the work because I will need to save everything in Firebase and if I do a query in Sqlite I will have to do it in Firebase too...

Or I Should change the implementation instead of Firebase using another database for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitly tell the Firebase SDK to stay offline by calling [`goOffline()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase#goOffline()), as shown in the documentation on [managing and detecting connection state](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state). Then you can write to the database, and all data will just be stored in the cache, and when the user signs in to their Google account, you can call `goOnline()` to enable synchronizing it to the cloud-hosted database.

That said, this is not an ideal approach for the Firebase Realtime Database, as the performance of its SDKs will deteriorate linearly with the number of local, unsynchronized writes. If you want to take this sort of approach, your better of using Firestore - as that SDK keeps up-to-date snapshots for speedy local performance even with many local writes.

---

Alternatively (and more idiomatic) is to not try and disable local writes, but instead:

1. Immediate [create an anonymous user account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth) when the user first starts the ap.
2. Write to the database with that UID.
3. [Link a Google sign-in account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking) when the user wants to sign in.

This way the UID is known in step 1 already (and will not change in step 3), and you can save the user data to Firebase locally and in the cloud right away.